# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I use hive as Db of my app, I created Adapter of my class, but when I try to run my app I took exception below............................................................................................................................................................................

```
E/flutter (14408): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
E/flutter (14408): #0      SubCategoryModelAdapter.read (package:lezzet_kitabi/subCategoryModel.g.dart:20:32)
E/flutter (14408): #1      BinaryReaderImpl.read (package:hive/src/binary/binary_reader_impl.dart:326:33)
E/flutter (14408): #2      BinaryReaderImpl.readFrame (package:hive/src/binary/binary_reader_impl.dart:274:26)
E/flutter (14408): #3      FrameHelper.framesFromBytes (package:hive/src/binary/frame_helper.dart:21:26)
E/flutter (14408): #4      FrameIoHelper.framesFromFile (package:hive/src/io/frame_io_helper.dart:42:12)
E/flutter (14408): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14408): #5      StorageBackendVm.initialize (package:hive/src/backend/vm/storage_backend_vm.dart:86:11)
E/flutter (14408): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14408): #6      HiveImpl._openBox (package:hive/src/hive_impl.dart:113:9)
E/flutter (14408): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14408): #7      HiveImpl.openBox (package:hive/src/hive_impl.dart:142:12)
E/flutter (14408): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14408): #8      main (package:lezzet_kitabi/main.dart:28:3)
E/flutter (14408): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14408):
```

I share class and its adapter

```
part 'subCategoryModel.g.dart';


@HiveType(typeId : 1)
class SubCategoryModel extends HiveObject{
  SubCategoryModel({
    this.subCategoryId,
    this.subCategoryImagePath,
    this.subCategoryName,
    this.categoryColor,
    this.recipeId,
    this.ingredients,
    this.recipePhotoDir,
    this.recordedVoiceDir});

  @HiveField(0)
  final int categoryColor;

  @HiveField(1)
  final double recipeId;

  @HiveField(2)
  bool isCompleted;

  @HiveField(3)
  int subCategoryId;

  @HiveField(4)
  String subCategoryImagePath;

  @HiveField(5)
  String subCategoryName;

  @HiveField(6)
  List <Ingredient> ingredients;

  @HiveField(7)
  String recipePhotoDir;

  @HiveField(8)
  String recordedVoiceDir;

}
```

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'subCategoryModel.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class SubCategoryModelAdapter extends TypeAdapter<SubCategoryModel> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1;

  @override
  SubCategoryModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return SubCategoryModel(
      subCategoryId: fields[3] as int,
      subCategoryImagePath: fields[4] as String,
      subCategoryName: fields[5] as String,
      categoryColor: fields[0] as int,
      recipeId: fields[1] as double,
      ingredients: (fields[6] as List)?.cast<Ingredient>(),
      recipePhotoDir: fields[7] as String,
      recordedVoiceDir: fields[8] as String,
    )..isCompleted = fields[2] as bool;
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, SubCategoryModel obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(9)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.categoryColor)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.recipeId)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.isCompleted)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.subCategoryId)
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..write(obj.subCategoryImagePath)
      ..writeByte(5)
      ..write(obj.subCategoryName)
      ..writeByte(6)
      ..write(obj.ingredients)
      ..writeByte(7)
      ..write(obj.recipePhotoDir)
      ..writeByte(8)
      ..write(obj.recordedVoiceDir);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is SubCategoryModelAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

Can you help me Thanks.

Comment: Could you try int.parse(fields[0]) instead of "as int"?

Comment: same error unfortunality :/

Comment: Which value do you have in fields[3] and fields[0]? 
What do you get when you print this value? 
print(fields[3]); 
print(fields[0]);

Comment: I/flutter (26142): images/sticker0.png
I/flutter (26142): 2152998005

Comment: those are outputs of prints it is wrong, field(3) is written subCategoryId but it printed subCategoryImagePath, also field(0) should be color val but returned different int can you help me :/

Comment: I think that you are not reading the data in the order you want to. The easiest solution is to print all the fields to know which data is in which field. After that, you will be able to correct the "return SubCategoryModel"

Comment: It solved after I cleaned data of the app thanks

Comment: I happy that your App now works :-).
You can close the question now.